# Insert values in id columns for foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have three tables as seen attached in the picture. I want to join these three tables and I insert all data from a form of the app in the `Produse`, `Clienti` and `Comenzi` tables.

Everything is OK except the two columns in the `Comenzi` table (`IDClient` and `IDProdus`). They are both of type `int` and foreign keys for the other two tables, and I can't make them `Identity` to auto increase id.

So the program crashes when I press the submit button in the app form.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IDClient', table 'dbo.Tmp_Comenzi'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

If I allow nulls, it throws no error but the column will be null. There is no value going inside these two columns from the app form so I have to find a way to provide a value for them or is there another way?

I can't fill them by hand. I am not very good at SQL joining and table relationships, maybe I did something wrong.

How can I insert my data successfully?

[image]

Well, i created 3 stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProducts]

@DenProd nvarchar(50),
@ProdQuant nvarchar(50),
@ProdSize nvarchar(50),
@ProdComm nvarchar(50)
```

AS

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Produse (Denumire, Cantitate, Dimensiuni, Comentarii) VALUES (@DenProd, @ProdQuant, @ProdSize, @ProdComm)
END
```

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertClients]

```
@NumeClient nvarchar(50)
```

AS

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Clienti (NumeClient) VALUES (@NumeClient)
END
```

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrders]

```
-- @ClientID int,
-- @ProductID int,
@StartDate date,
@FinishDate date,
@Billed nvarchar(50),
@Delivered nvarchar(50)
```

AS

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Comenzi (IDClient) SELECT IDClient FROM Clienti;
    INSERT INTO Comenzi (IDProdus) SELECT IDProdus FROM Produse;
    INSERT INTO Comenzi (DataInceput, DataSfarsit, Facturata, Livrata) VALUES (@StartDate, @FinishDate, @Billed, @Delivered)
END
```

The first two procedures work perfectly. The third is the problem.

The insertion code:

```
private void InsertOrderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd =  new SqlCommand("InsertClients", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeClient", textBoxClientNou.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        textBoxClientNou.Text = "";

        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListaProduse.Items)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("InsertProducts", con);
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DenProd", item.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdQuant", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdSize", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdComm", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("InsertOrders", con);

        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dateTimePicker1.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishDate", dateTimePicker2.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billed", factstatus);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delivered", livstatus);
        con.Open();
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        comboBoxClient.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker1.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker2.Text = "";
        textBoxClientNou.Text = "";
        ListaProduse.Items.Clear();
      
        MessageBox.Show("Succesful insert");
        
    }
```

Now i get these errors:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IDProdus', table 'DatabaseName.dbo.Comenzi'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IDClient', table 'DatabaseName.dbo.Comenzi'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

In the InsertOrders procedure i tried to insert the values from the other tables but nothing. I tried all kinds of queries.

Now i ended up with this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("InsertProducts", con);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in ListaProduse.Items)
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DenProd", item.Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdQuant", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdSize", item.SubItems[1].Text);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdComm", item.SubItems[1].Text);
        }

        var IDProductParameter = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ProdID", SqlDbType.Int);
        IDProductParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        con.Open();
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var IDProdus = (int)IDProductParameter.Value;
        con.Close();
```

It is for a listview with four columns which sends values in the database. It works perfect for 1 product. If i add another product on the list and insert it in the database, i get the error:

Procedure or function InsertProducts has too many arguments specified.

This is the procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProducts]
@DenProd nvarchar(50),
@ProdQuant nvarchar(50),
@ProdSize nvarchar(50),
@ProdComm nvarchar(50),
    @ProdID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Produse (Denumire, Cantitate, Dimensiuni, Comentarii) VALUES (@DenProd, @ProdQuant, @ProdSize, @ProdComm);
    SELECT @ProdID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Comment: "i can't make them Identity to auto increase id", why are you unable to do this?

Comment: Data should be inserted first in Produse, Clienti table and then identity column value from both table should be properly mapped to insert into  Comenzi table. Issue seems in your mapping where you are passing value of both key from your app.

Comment: Just use EF Core; it'll do all this for you

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @ChristianPhillips - Because the field IDComanda from the Comenzi table is already Identity increment and can't have more than 1 field like that. If i make the other increment, it turns off the previous one.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to have the child end of the relationship as autoincrement, because then you wouldn't be able to set the value, and you need to be able to se tthe value to create a related record

Comment: *the program crashes when I press the submit button in the app form.*  Then might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] reproducing the problem?  From [ask]: *if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*  As it is we can only guess what you are doing wrong, so you're more likely to get help if we don't have to guess -- because you have told us.

Comment: When you insert in product and client, you need to assign the rows ID values.  Then use those ID in your Comenzi inserts.

Answer (score 0):

First you insert Produse and Clienti tables and get those ID and send these values when inserting Comenzi table. How you get those I am sharing sample stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usp_Insert_Produse
    @col1         VARCHAR(50),
    @new_identity INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO Produse(col1)
    VALUES (@col1)

    SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SELECT @new_identity AS id

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first two stored procedures should have output parameters to return the new IDClient and IDProdus. The application code can then receive the values and submit them as parameters to the third stored procedure.

Here's the first step as an example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertClients]
@NumeClient nvarchar(50),
@IDClient INT OUTUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Clienti (NumeClient) VALUES (@NumeClient);
    SELECT @IDClient = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Application

```
SqlCommand cmd =  new SqlCommand("InsertClients", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumeClient", textBoxClientNou.Text);
var IDClientParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDClient", SqlDbType.Int);
IDClientParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var IDClient = (int) IDClientParameter.Value;
con.Close();
```